# Why is my CSS media query ignored by mobile phones?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have 3 media queries in my CSS which seem to work fine when I resize the browser, but don't when I use the responsive design tool from the inspector ("toggle device mode") and on mobile phones.

Here is part of my CSS :

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {


  body {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {


  body {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #slider_container {
    float: none;
    padding-top: 2em;
    width: 75%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  #slide_desc {
    //

    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #353535;
/* line-height: 2em; */
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: georgia;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  #slider_container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 1em;
  }

  #menu_button {
    display: block;
    width: 2em;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #top_menu {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: 3em;
    /* background-color: gray; */
  }

  #top_menu>ul {
    margin-top: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #top_menu>ul>li {
    margin: 0;
    /* background-color:red !important; */
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }

  #top_menu>ul>li>a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
    height: auto;
  }

  #slides_container {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The first 2 media queries always work fine, but the 3rd gets ignored. The 3rd media query only works if the browser itself is resized below 768px.

I know there are other similar questions, but are mostly related to the use of `!important`, or misplacement of the queries. My queries are at the end of the file, and what's strange is they do work if the browser is resized.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you setting the viewport to `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"`?

Comment: I just added that and now it works fine. Though I have no idea what that does.Can you please add that with an explanation maybe so I can accept you answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your viewport meta tag to `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"`. This tells the browser to render the width of the page at the width of the device's screen. So if that screen is 320px wide, the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed out and showing 960px (or whatever that device does by default).

**HTML**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to
>   a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value
>   device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a
>   scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height
>   values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size
>   or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is
>   first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable
>   properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

You can read more about the viewport meta tag and how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a syntax error:

```css
  #slide_desc {
    //
```

Double-slashes are not valid in CSS.

Comment: well I did a search for '//' and replaced any with /* */ also removed that lone // you found ... but didn't do any difference

Comment: @vlatkozelka Of the code provided, that is the only thing wrong with it. And that error would have stopped continued processing of the CSS document, which would have caused the problem you encountered. After removing that line and passing it through http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ everything is shown to be valid.

Comment: I know you are right, your answer is well noted. I was just saying it didn't seem to be the issue. I think the browser engine ignores the declaration when it finds a syntax error and passes on... that's why the // seemed to work like comment, and it wasn't clear that it wasn't.